# Impossible to construct collision resistant hash function from one way function

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, one-way-function

[[Simon 98]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0054137.pdf) showed that it is impossible to construct collision resistant hash function from one way functions in a black-box way. I read the paper but barely understood it. Is there any source, where I can find a simpler explanation of the result?
I would appreciate if you could provide me some papers that explain any other black-box impossibility results in a simple to understand way.